# Added multiple functions to prototype, but can't call a function from within another for some reason

Tags: javascript

I did this:

```
function SomeClass(a) {
  this.a = a;
};

SomeClass.prototype = {

   f1: function() {
     // ...
   },

   f2: function() {

      f1();
   }

};
```

And I am getting the error:

```
f1 is not defined
```

I tried adding 'this.' to the call, but that didn't work either.

**WHat could the issue be?**

*P.S there was a great online javascript book (not this one: http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/), and it even had a little console window on the bottom of the html page to test things out, any ideas?*

Comment: Use Firebug or the Chrome console.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SomeClass.prototype.f1 = function() {};
SomeClass.prototype.f2 = function() { this.f1(); };
```

Comment: Are you doing it like this - "var x = new SomeClass(); x.f2();"?

Comment: @codecompleting: The original example works in chrome, after sobstituting `f2` with `f2: function() { this.f1(); }`. Which **browser** are you using?